# Cannot Boot Ubuntu - TTY1 login loop

Tags: boot, 18.04, login, tty

Upon removing a particular package, I think I removed some very important stuff from my Ubuntu 18.04.
When I login, I get the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS `tty1` screen.
It prompts me to login.
I enter my username and password.
A screen with Last login info appears briefly and it get me back to login prompt.

I tried recovery mode. It says Login service failed. But it gets me to the `tty1` screen after some time. And then the same happens...login loop.

I cannot get in.
But I need to login.
I have work to do.

I already tried <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, but it did not work.

Comment: Which "particular package" did you remove?

Comment: I installed Mavensmate. Then tried to remove it. I think I messed up with the commands. And important pkgs got removed.

Comment: Nobody can help you without knowing which important pkgs got removed. Back up your personal data, documents, pictures, etc. and reinstall.

Comment: How do I backup my stuffs please? I cannot login.

Comment: Try booting from the Live USB/DVD you used to install Ubuntu. Select the "Try Ubuntu without installing" option. Then use a different USB external drive in a different port (don't unplug the Live USB, if using Live USB) to copy your folders.

Comment: This is expirienced in Ubuntu 17.10 what i did was simply enter wrong password once then the right password it worked ike a charm XD idont know why

Comment: You're lucky @Jatin-CBS. I just tried your trick and it did not work for me. :( I'm being prompted to login over and over again, even after entering correct username and password.

Comment: Try this workaround here https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop

Comment: @Jatin-CBS, checked that one already. No FN keys are working. Cannot type any command either. Just stuck on login/password. I don't get it. I think the only option is to reinstall Ubuntu. What do you think?

Comment: Thanks @user68186. I managed to get my data and I ended up reinstalling Ubuntu. I am able to work normally now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)